# Using Propel ORM in PHP project

Tags: php, mysql, xml, orm

I'm new to [propel](/questions/tagged/propel), and I want to use it in a phonebook PHP project.

I installed Propel via composer and generated the `schema.xml` file and the `propel.xml` configuration file, but when I start coding with PHP it says

> fatal error:  Class 'Contact' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\phonebook\index.php

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->setFirstname('Jane');
    $contact->setLastname('Austen');
    $contact->setImage('images/image.png');
    $contact->setPhonenumber(0954957394);
    $contact->setEmail('whatever@whatever.com');
    $contact->save();
?>
```

and here's my `schema.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore">
    <table name="contact" idMethod="native" phpName="Contact">
        <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
        <column name="firstname" phpName="Firstname" type="VARCHAR" size="15"/>
        <column name="lastname" phpName="Lastname" type="VARCHAR" size="15" required="true"/>
        <column name="image" phpName="Image" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
        <column name="phonenumber" phpName="Phonenumber" type="INTEGER"/>
        <column name="email" phpName="Email" type="VARCHAR" size="30" required="true"/>
        <vendor type="mysql">
            <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
        </vendor>
    </table>
</database>
```

I think the problem is simple, but I'm not getting what is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the autoload file that composer creates for you.

If you're using default settings this would be:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
```

Comment: I tried this, but still dosen't work.
I used propel init command to generate the schema and configuration files, is there any problem with that??

Comment: Where is the file that includes the class definition for Contact included?

Comment: I don't know, where I can find it??

Comment: The problem is that you're not including that file into your code.  PHP doesn't know what the Contact class is because you're never defining the class for it.